# Unable to get total count value

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery code and i am Unable to get total count value (`total_cnt`).

i need to get value of `per_count` and multiply it with `per_days`

This is my jquery code (not working):-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var per_count = '';
  $('#hpersons').keyup(function() { 
    var per_cnt = this.value;
    var per_count = per_cnt;
  });
  $('#hdays').keyup(function() { 
    var per_days = this.value; 
    var total_cnt = var per_count * var per_days; 
    $('#hfare').html(total_cnt);
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to remove unnecessary `var` from every-where.

2.Don't mix jQuery and javascript syntaxes with each-other.Use either-one purily.

Code need to be like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total_cnt;
  var per_count;
  $('#hpersons').keyup(function() { 
    per_count = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#hdays').keyup(function() { 
     per_days = $(this).val();
    var total_cnt = per_count * per_days; 
    $('#hfare').html(total_cnt);
  }); 
});
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total_cnt;
  var per_count;
  $('#hpersons').keyup(function() { 
    per_count = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#hdays').keyup(function() { 
     per_days = $(this).val();
    var total_cnt = per_count * per_days; 
    $('#hfare').val(total_cnt);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hpersons"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="hdays"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="hfare">
```

Comment: I agree about not mixing jQuery/native JS, but for simply access a properties (ie. `this.value`) I think exceptions can be made. There's little point creating an entire jQuery object and accessing it just to get a value you already have access to.

Comment: how to get total_cnt into php variable.

Comment: @RaghuVenkataa  for that you have to send that value to php page using ajax and assign that value to your desired php variable

Comment: @AlivetoDie is it possible to get that total_cnt value into input field instead of <div>

Comment: @RaghuVenkataa  why not. check my edited solution. you need to use `.val()` instead of `.html()` to put value into input text filed.